# DISCORD.JS - I get an error when I'm using "member.roles.set([role1,role2] How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want the bot to remove all the existant roles and replace them with some others

Little part of the code (the important one)

```
if(command == "promote"){
const member = message.mentions.members.first();

let test1 = member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "÷Test1÷")
let test2 = member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "∸Test2∸")
let test3 = member.roles.cache.some(r => r.name === "≎Test3≎")

if(!member){ return message.channel.send("Mention a player to promote.")}
      if (test1) {
        member.roles.set([test2, test3]);
        message.channel.send(`Promoted succesfully ${member}`);
        client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "promotions").send(`**PROMOTION**\n${member} TEST1 -> TEST2 AND TEST3`)

      }
}
```

Instead of replacing roles, it removes all the roles.
`(node:251) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body roles[1]: The set already contains this value`

Also I sometimes get this error
`(node:317) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.`

Comment: `Array.some` returns a boolean value, did you mean to use `Array.find`? (also, always use `console.log()` to make sure variables actually contain what you think they contain)

Comment: How to use Array.find? Because I tried changing `Array.some` by `Array.find` and this time nothing happened

Comment: Look at MDN to know what a native function does.

Comment: Can you send me the link to the page?

Comment: Just google "array find": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find